# And all the Army of Hashem Left

Tags: bo, passover, parshanut-torah-comment

What does the Posuk mean when it says all of the Army of Hashem Left when did Bnei Yisroel turn into an Army or is it referring to Bnei Yisroel?

יָצְאוּ כָּל **צִבְאוֹת יְ־הֹוָ־ה** מֵאֶרֶץ מִצְרָיִם

Comment: Your translation of "צבאות" is assuming it means "army [sic] of". I think this question is on the translator and not the פסוק.

Comment: So what is Tzivos?

Comment: and it is sort of irrelevant as  the question is when else but here are we called Tzivos

Comment: The רמב"ן at the beginning of במדבר on "לצבאתם" says it can mean large numbers of people.

Comment: Large Number of people!?!?! especially since only about one percent of Klal Yisroel left Mitzrayim and the rest died in Makos of darkness I think you Should try again

Comment: SimchasTorah, your last point is a question from this pasuk, specifically the word "כָּל," on that Midrash, not the other way around.

Comment: No, its part of the answer see the question,focus on this aspect read deeper into the text, specifically: or is it referring to Bnei Yisroel?

Comment: look who it refers to the other times it is used

Comment: @SimchasTorah Consider rephrasing the question to clearly ask for exactly the information you seek. I am not sure what you are getting at.

Comment: There is a shiur on this page that brings many commentaries on this: http://www.insidechassidus.org/winter/214-parshas-bo/1067-parsha-classes-bo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a simpler level, wouldn't it just be meant to stress that the Jewish People left Egypt in an organized way, not as an undisciplined rabble of fleeing slaves?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the answer is the Seforim Hakedoshim say this Posuk is not referring to Bnei Yisreol but the the angels and other heavenly beings the ARMIES of Hashem that went out with Klal Yisroel,as they did some of the work to double it, so the Jews could go out early to make up for the missing years, they added workers that is these angels to the desert, Hence most times throughout Nach it uses the word  צבאת it is referring to Hashem or his Heavenly angels.

Comment: This was also my initial inclination. Do you have a source?